# Omniauth-Facebook giving error in callback - Email can't be blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, devise

Hi my devise login appears to work, but for some reason Facebook is not sending me the email in my API request. Then I am getting this error:  [image]

I read up on the July 18th, 2015 adjustment and added scope. No luck. Here is the initializer:

> config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_KEY'],
>   ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], scope: 'email', info_fields:'email,name'

Maybe I'm missing something on the FB Developer Page?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to handle it :

- Some Facebook users have unverified emails, so Facebook will not give it to you
- There is Facebook users with only telephone numbers and no email
- Facebook allow the user to not provide some information to your app, for example the email

Answer (score 0):

It happens with profiles with unverified emails and when user choose not to provide your app with their email

rescue that error and redirect user to normal sign up page so they continue with providing their email address

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if what Nicolas is saying is correct then you can easily solve this problem. Before save populate some fake and unique email with "+":

Add to your User model something like this:

```
class User  < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_validation :adjust_email, on: :create


  private

    def adjust_email
      self.email = "fake+#{generate_token}" if email.blank?
      true
    end

    def generate_token
      rand(36**8).to_s(36)
    end

end
```

And you will have to show your user this fake email, so that she will be able to login with it later. A downside of this solution is that you will not be able to send emails to such users, but maybe you don't want to.

What Remon suggested is also a valid option to redirect to sign up in case you get this particular error.

So, it all depends on what you actually plan to do with the email.